# How can I calculate a smooth tangent wave that has no periodic delays?

Tags: graphing-functions, tangent-line

I want to use a tangent function to create a waveform that always passes itself back to -1 at the end of each cycle to 1.

When a tangent function only moves between -1 and 1, there is a gap left between each tangent path on the x axis.
[image]

I perfectly filled the area by simply using a second tangent of `n + pi/2` which filled the region, to create the repeating tangent I wanted.
[image]

I then tried to combine the formulas using the minimum function, but it seems to cut the graph in half, all values above 0 are just missing, which is not what I want.
[image]

How can I get a repeating tangent between y -1 and 1 that never has x axis gaps?

(I drew the y > 1 and y < -1 to represent my use case, where any value below -1 and above 1 are useless)

[Graph on desmos here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2kkpwtj8we)

[image]

My end goal is to create a formula that can essentially do this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider one branch of the tangent function. You're restricting the range of $\tan(x)$ to $[-1,1]$, which means $x\in\left[-\frac\pi4,\frac\pi4\right]$.

Since $\tan(x) = \tan(x\pm n\pi)$ for integer $n$, restricting the range to $[-1,1]$ for the entire plot of $\tan(x)$ would make for a domain of $\cdots\cup\left[-\frac{5\pi}4,-\frac{3\pi}4\right]\cup\left[-\frac\pi4,\frac\pi4\right]\cup\left[\frac{3\pi}4,\frac{5\pi}4\right]\cdots$. We can write this compactly by observing

$$x\in\left[-\frac{5\pi}4,-\frac{3\pi}4\right] \implies -\frac\pi4 \le x+\pi \le\frac\pi4 \implies |x+\pi| \le\frac\pi4$$

$$x \in \left[-\frac\pi4, \frac\pi4\right] \implies -\frac\pi4 \le x \le \frac\pi4 \implies |x| \le \frac\pi4$$

$$x\in\left[\frac{3\pi}4,\frac{5\pi}4\right] \implies -\frac\pi4 \le x-\pi \le\frac\pi4 \implies |x-\pi| \le\frac\pi4$$

and so on, such that the restricted domain is $|x+n\pi|\le\frac\pi4$, where $n$ is an integer.

We can fill in the gaps by shifting $\tan(x)$ by $\frac\pi2$, as the other answer suggests. Then we could define this function piecewise as

$$\operatorname{smoothtan}(x) = \begin{cases} \tan(x) & \text{if } |x+n\pi|\le\frac\pi4 \quad (n\in\mathbb Z) \\ \tan\left(x\pm\frac\pi2\right) & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

(though ["smooth"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness) is not the best name for this function)

Comment: Thanks, and yeah, smooth definitely wasnt exactly the term I was looking for... maybe.. sawtoothed tangent?

Answer (score 1):

I would write the following in Desmos: $$y = \left[\tan(x),\tan\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right] \{-1 \le y \le 1\}$$

[Here is a link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g7yzravasq) for the same page you sent with the formula written.

Comment: thankyou, this is pretty much what I was looking for

Comment: actually, I do have one more question. Is there a way to do this with traditional math? (Not desmos syntax, just a formula to create a repeating tangent, and it doesnt need to check if its actually between -1 and 1)

Comment: @MisterSirCode my first thought when seeing your question was to write $\frac{tan(x)}/{x}$ and then $\frac{tan(3x)}/{x}$ (to narrow the graph) but it leaves small gaps, and I'm not sure if that is ok to you. If there is a formula with no gaps, I don't know it

Comment: You can not define a non continuous function which has no poles, but is jumping, by any of the known periodic functions, so you have to define it in intervals or use the fourrier series